# Utf8ToString and older Delphi versions

Tags: delphi

I want to use some units in both older and newer versions of Delphi. Since a recent Delphi version, `Utf8Decode` throws a deprecated warning which advises to switch to `Utf8ToString`. Problem is older versions of Delphi don't declare this function, so which `{$IFDEF}`label should I use to define a wrapper around `Utf8Decode` named `Utf8String` (or perhaps `Utf8ToWideString`)?

Or in other words: which version was `Utf8ToString` introduced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I would implement it with an `$IF` so that calling code can use either the new RTL function, or fall back on the older deprecated version. Since the new `UTF8ToString` returns a UnicodeString I think it is safe to assume that it was introduced in Delphi 2009.

```
{$IF not Declared(UTF8ToString)}
function UTF8ToString(const s: UTF8String): WideString;
begin
  Result := UTF8Decode(s);
end;
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: another question: would I gain performance if I did it like this:´


      type
        TUtf8DecodeFunc=function(const S: UTF8String): WideString;
      var
        UTF8ToStringX:TUtf8DecodeFunc;

      initialization
      {$IF Declared(UTF8ToString)}
        UTF8ToStringX:=UTF8ToString;
      {$ELSE}
        UTF8ToStringX:=UTF8Decode;
      {$IFEND}´

Comment: that wouldn't gain you anything that you could measure

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember:

- `UTF8String` and associated `UTF8Encode / UTF8Decode` were introduced in Delphi 6;
- `UTF8ToWideString` and `UTF8ToString` were introduced in Delphi 2009 (i.e. Unicode version), as such:

  ```
  function UTF8Decode(const S: RawByteString): WideString; 
     deprecated 'Use UTF8ToWideString or UTF8ToString';
  ```

In order to get rid of this compatibility issue, you can either define your own `UTF8ToString`  function (as David propose), or either use your own implementation.

I rewrote some (perhaps) faster version for our framework, which works also with Delphi 5 (I wanted to add UTF-8 support for some legacy Delphi 5 code, some 3,000,000 source code lines with third party components which stops easy upgrade - at least for the manager's decision). See all corresponding `RawUTF8` type in [SynCommons.pas](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas):

```
{$ifdef UNICODE}
function UTF8DecodeToString(P: PUTF8Char; L: integer): string;
begin
  result := UTF8DecodeToUnicodeString(P,L);
end;
{$else}
function UTF8DecodeToString(P: PUTF8Char; L: integer): string;
var Dest: RawUnicode;
begin
  if GetACP=CODEPAGE_US then begin
    if (P=nil) or (L=0) then
      result := '' else begin
      SetLength(Dest,L); // faster than Windows API / Delphi RTL
      SetString(result,PAnsiChar(pointer(Dest)),UTF8ToWinPChar(pointer(Dest),P,L));
    end;
    exit;
  end;
  result := '';
  if (P=nil) or (L=0) then
    exit;
  SetLength(Dest,L*2);
  L := UTF8ToWideChar(pointer(Dest),P,L) shr 1;
  SetLength(result,WideCharToMultiByte(GetACP,0,pointer(Dest),L,nil,0,nil,nil));
  WideCharToMultiByte(GetACP,0,pointer(Dest),L,pointer(result),length(result),nil,nil);
end;
{$endif}
```